# Using XAMPP Install of MySQL with Netbeans 6.8/MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, netbeans, osx-snow-leopard, xampp

All,

For all of this I am using Mac OSX Snow Leopard.

I have happily used XAMPP to develop PHP backed sites in the past with no problems(as you'd expect for such a simple to set up package). I am now trying to set up this MySQL install in Netbeans 6.8 (for now just trying to get a sample database backed webapp to run). My issue is that even though MySQL has been started I cannot connect to it at 127.0.0.1 on port 3306 (which it is set up to use).

I have read that the issue is that XAMPP holds MySQl.sock in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/... whereas MySQL Workbench and Netbeans expects to find it in /tmp/MySQL.sock. Is this correct? I've tried to set up a symbolic link from /tmp to the xmapp directory but this doesn't appear to have changed anything.

Is there anything else I can try/anything that I am missing?

Comment: If you specify the MySQL server as 127.0.0.1 (instead of localhost) it usually forces a connect over TCP/IP not the unix socket.  Can you telnet to 127.0.0.1:3306 using OS X's Terminal?

Comment: By the way, Workbench on OS X has got more problems than the socket being in the wrong place - I had multiple crashes, it couldn't work out when a remote server was running so it sometimes didn't show me the database list correctly.  The command-line it created to launch the backup/restore programs was incorrect.  I ended up scrapping it entirely.

Comment: I have been using 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost after reading that it's not always resolved correctly. 

The only reason I tried MySQL workbench was because I was after a tool which should be able to connect easily! Do you know of a tool which will allow me to specify where it should look for the socket? If this then worked then it would verify that the miplaced socket was the issue? Would it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this to work. So in case anyone else is reading this and wondering what happened... I installed a non XAMPP instance of the MySQL database and am using that now instead. Less than ideal but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded from an older version of XAMPP to 1.7.3 and encountered a the same problem, I got MySQL Workbench to connect if I edited the my.ini file and:

changed the socket parameter to:
socket                  = "TCP/IP"

made mysql bind to an IP address or all IP as  in the case below:

## enable-named-pipe

bind-address=0.0.0.0

This requires that you disable named-pipe (as shown above)